# Can react.memo be used to memoise any pure function or just components?

Tags: reactjs

Title says it all. Mainly I am wondering if `react.memo` can replace my memoizeOne library.

Comment: React docs explains well why one may need `.memo` method

Comment: I think you might need [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook (beware, it's not yet production ready).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Please check [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) on `memo`